# Can't find model 'en' in Rasa using Python

Tags: python, chatbot, spacy, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I'm new to Rasa NLU and I'm trying to train my bot by typing `python nlu_model.py` on the cmd.

However, it gives this error: OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a data directory.

[image: Error shown in cmd]

I researched on other forums and sites how to solve this error and they recommended `python -m spacy download en`. It works, however...

[image]

However, I still get the error from above when I try to type `python nlu_model.py` in the cmd. What could be the problem in this? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am new to Rasa and I am just following this video tutorial in Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xu6D_vLP5vY&t=201s

Answer (score 0):

The line "you dont have sufficient privilege to perform this operation" suggests that you are lacking permission.
So could you please either run `python -m spacy download en` in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or you run your terminal as Administrator. Both approaches are also described here: https://spacy.io/usage/#symlink-privilege

Answer (score 0):

A working, but dirty way of solving it would be to just copy/paste the `en_core_web_sm` folder from the first to the second directory and renaming it as `en`.

It's not future-proof because you'd need to re-do it every time you update Spacy...

Using conda environments didn't work for some reasons on my limited access company laptop.